# How to create an integer composed of data from two different data lines?

Tags: python, integer, data-science

I am trying to define the variable ini_f in my code below as the last three characters of the line with 'CAFE' being the most significant digits and the second, third, and forth characters of the line following the CAFE line to be the three least significant digits.

```
with open('data.txt', "r") as dataset:
    for line in dataset:
        if 'CAFE' in line:
            ini_f = line[5:], line+1[1:4]
            print(ini_f)
        else: 
            pass
```

Comment: Do you mean `for line in dataset.readlines()`?

Comment: Please provide input data.txt file. And example what output do you want

Comment: Олег Гребчук the output that I want is a 6 digit number (the first three digits of which come from the line with 'CAFE' in it and the last three digits come from the line following the 'CAFE' line. I am looking for a way to tell the computer to move to the next line and to take three characters from that next line.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track if you found 'CAFE' in a line with the help of a true/false variable. If you did not find 'CAFE' in a line, you can set it back to false.
This is the example code:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as dataset:
    ini_f = ''
    found_cafe = False
    for line in dataset:
        if found_cafe:
            ini_f += line[-4:-1]
            print(ini_f)
        if 'CAFE' in line:
            ini_f = line[:3]
            found_cafe = True
        else:
            found_cafe = False
            ini_f = ''
```

I used this file to test the functionality:

```
Loremipsumdolorsitamet
conseteturCAFEsadipscingelitr
seddiamnonumyeirmodtempor
inviduntutlaboreetdolore
magnaaliquyameratseddiamvoluptua
AtveroCAFEeosetaccusametjusto
duodoloreseCAFEtearebum
Stetclitakasdgubergren
noseatakimatasanctus
```

Giving this output:

```
conpor
Atvbum
duoren
```

We extract the first three digits with line[:3] and the last 3 **readable** digits with line[-4:-1], because the last digit is a newline (\n).

Comment: Happy to hear that! Please accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: hi Chris! are the two empty quotes defining the ini_f variable supposed to be filled with text? or left blank?

Comment: After checking again, I recognized that you can in fact delete the first ini_f = ''. I added it to prevent an error when trying to add something to ini_f if it's not defined yet. But in the above code this case is not possible to happen.